# Signature Pad not working in IE7

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer, digital-signature

I have the following signature pad.

```
     <form method=post action="#" class=sigPad>        
               <label for=name>Print your name</label>        
               <input type=text name=name id=name class=name>        
               <p class="drawItDesc">Draw your signature</p>        
               <div class="sig sigWrapper"> <div class=typed></div>        
               <canvas class=pad width="585px" height="200px"></canvas>        
               <input type=hidden name=output class=output> </div>        
               <button type="submit" id="agree" style="opacity:0.2">I accept the terms of this agreement.</button>        
      </form>
```

This is the function called when needed.

```
   function drawSigPad(){
         $('.sigPad').signaturePad({drawOnly:true});
            }
```

What happens is when the user presses a button the signature pad is drawn. This works fine in Chrome and FF however it breaks in IE non-compatibility mode. It works as long as non compatibility is not switched on.

The error I get is as follows.

```
   SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'getContext': object is null or undefined 
          jquery.signaturepad.min.js, line 246 character 1
```

The line in question is this

```
    i.bind("selectstart.signaturepad",function(a){
return c(a.target).is(":input")
});
```

Anyone know why IE7 breaks this? Or a way around this problem.

EDIT: Sorry about the confusion, I am using IE9 browser and using non-compatibility mode as well as using the browser tools to check IE7.

Comment: IE8 and earlier don't support `<canvas>`.

Comment: Is IE8 affected? If the answer is yes, then its potentially a canvas issue. Also just to be clear: are you saying it works in IE7 in non-compatibility mode, but breaks with IE7+compatibility mode?

Comment: Seems to work when using his code on IE7 from http://thomasjbradley.ca/lab/signature-pad/accept/

Comment: Yeah, it seems IE8 also breaks with it. Any ideas on how to fix that?

Comment: Answer updated with browser usage.

Comment: Just to be explicit: are you saying it breaks on IE9 with Browser Mode set to IE7 and Document Mode set to Quirks?

Comment: I am using IE 9 with browser mode set to IE7 and Document mode set to IE7.

Comment: Any ideas on whats causing it even?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE7 doesn't support the `canvas` tag.
It only supported in IE8+.

[here](http://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/) is a nifty way to get a canvas tag, and any other html5 tag, working in IE7 & 8.

It's called explorercanvas and it simulates the canvas, allowing pretty much any browser to display your sig pad.

the best thing is, all you need to do is add a single `<script>` tag.